# Don't understand why I'm getting a NameError for a variable

Tags: python, variables

I have a Tic Tac Toe game in Python, and right now its giving me a weird "Name Error". Here is the error:

```
NameError: name 'newspace' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
global newSpace
newSpace = " "

#Check for a win function:
def checkWin(player):
  if player == "X":
    newSpace = "" #
  else:
    newSpace = "" #
  if spaces[0] == player and spaces[1] == player and spaces[2] == player:
    spaces[0] = newspace
    spaces[1] = newspace
    spaces[2] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[3] == player and spaces[4] == player and spaces[5] == player:
    spaces[3] = newspace
    spaces[4] = newspace
    spaces[5] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[6] == player and spaces[7] == player and spaces[8] == player:
    spaces[6] = newspace
    spaces[7] = newspace
    spaces[8] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[0] == player and spaces[3] == player and spaces[6] == player:
    spaces[0] = newspace
    spaces[3] = newspace
    spaces[6] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[1] == player and spaces[4] == player and spaces[7] == player:
    spaces[1] = newspace
    spaces[4] = newspace
    spaces[7] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[2] == player and spaces[5] == player and spaces[8] == player:
    spaces[2] = newspace
    spaces[5] = newspace
    spaces[8] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[0] == player and spaces[4] == player and spaces[8] == player:
    spaces[0] = newspace
    spaces[4] = newspace
    spaces[8] = newspace
    return True
  if spaces[2] == player and spaces[4] == player and spaces[6] == player:
    spaces[2] = newspace
    spaces[4] = newspace
    spaces[6] = newspace
    return True
  return False
```

I know it's not the most efficient code, but i'm a beginner. In the top, I define newSpace and make it global, so I don't understand why it's giving me this error. Anyone know why? Thanks.

For reference, you can see my whole code here: https://repl.it/@LoveTheBears101/Tic-Tac-Toe. This is from line 1 - 67

Comment: Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: Do you even need a global variable for this? What is the purpose of the program, and this function?

Comment: What should I do to catch that error?

Comment: You need to put the `global newSpace` _inside_ the function. Where you have it does nothing. (This is in addition to spelling it properly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case-sensitivity: `newspace` != `newSpace`

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response, I should probably be more careful. My finished project is here: https://tic-tac-toe.lovethebears101.repl.run/

Comment: @LoveTheBears101 - If you like this answer, press the Accept button!

Comment: This likely isn't the only problem.

Comment: I don't know if @martineau is referring to only the NameError, but I agree that the code seems to have many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `global newSpace`, it is not required here, if the `newSpace` is not declared earlier.